# Why can't i SSH into my EC2 instance if my security group is allowing TCP on Port 22 and there is no Network Access Control List?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel

I have an ec2 instance that i want to use as an SSH tunnel for MySQL Workbench.

Its access is locked down to My IP, Port 22 for TCP traffic. There is no NACL.

I can start a session in Systems Manager Session Manager and see the instance is working and can ping public URLs.

The key pair is in the folder from where i am running the following command:

```
ssh -i "key-pair.pem" ec2-user@11.22.33.44
```

However, the operation times out from my terminal and also when i try to connect via MySQL Workbench. Can anyone help?

If i add `-vvv`  to the command i get the following output

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 11.22.33.44 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 11.22.33.44  [11.22.33.44] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 11.22.33.44 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host 11.22.33.44 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: Please try `ssh -vvv -i "key-pair.pem" ec2-user@11.22.33.44` and show us the debug output.

Comment: is your instance on a public subnet (i.e. a subnet with an internet gateway attached do it)?  without this, there is no inbound route from the internet to your instance... session manager does not require public internet access to work

Comment: It is a public subnet. I have added the -vvv output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that my VPN was using a different IP to what the MyIP option in the security group was choosing so my requests were rejected at the security group level.